# MySQL JOIN Not Using Primary Key When Joining on Result Returned From Function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, join, primary-key, stored-functions

### Description

I'm trying to `JOIN` a table using the result of a stored function. The stored function returns an unsigned integer, which is the same type as the field I'm joining against.

**Problem**

The field I'm trying to `JOIN` to is a primary key. My issue is that MySQL doesn't seem to be using the primary key here.

The relevant lines of the query (shown below) are:

```
   LEFT JOIN second_db.s
     ON s.id = first_db.find_spend_id(qi.other_type, qi.other_id)
```

If I replace my function call `first_db.find_spend_id(...)` with an integer, for example `30`, `EXPLAIN` shows that the primary key is used, and the query is fast. If I use my function, `EXPLAIN` shows that the primary key is not used, and the query is slow.

**Question**

Is there some way I can use my function *and* have MySQL use the primary key when using the result of this function in this join? How should I modify my code in order to attain this most glorious resolution?

### Information

**Query**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM   first_db.qhr
   JOIN first_db.qi
     ON qi.id = qhr.issue_id
        AND qhr.status = 'Accepted'
   LEFT JOIN second_db.s
     ON s.id = first_db.find_spend_id(qi.other_type, qi.other_id)
   JOIN second_db.spend_reports AS sr
     ON sr.id = s.spend_report_id
   JOIN first_db.companies AS b
     ON b.id = s.member_id
   JOIN first_db.brands
     ON brands.id = sr.brand_id
LIMIT  0, 10
```

**Function**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` FUNCTION `find_spend_id`(lookup_other_type ENUM('One', 'Two'), lookup_other_id INT(10)) 
    RETURNS int(10)
    READS SQL DATA
    BEGIN
        (...snip actual code...)
        return 30;
    END
```

**Explain**

```
id   select_type    table    type    possible_keys    key    key_len    ref    rows    Extra
(...snip...)
1    SIMPLE         s        ALL      NULL            NULL   NULL       NULL   5999    "Using join buffer"
(...snip...)
```

Comment: Have you tried create a new stored procedure that calls your first one to generate the query for each result of the first?  That might be more efficient if its a small number of results.  Otherwise have you considered creating a temporary table of the results and doing a `JOIN` against that?  Just thinking out loud here.

Comment: The function actually calls a stored procedure that searches back through a chain of rows recursively until it finds a desired result - the `spend_id` used to `JOIN` here.

Comment: As long as your field in JOIN is calculated there is no way for the engine to take advantage of the INDEX correctly. This will happen on MySQL server level always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, what I wanted to achieve was not possible with this approach.